# custom event handling for variable source names

Tags: java

I'm creating a menu with a submenu that i want to display the clients in a list. Right now the clients get added to the submenu which displays their first and last names.

```
menuItemNames.add(((Person)model.get(i)).getfName() + " "+ ((Person)model.get(i)).getlName());
            for (int x=0; x<menuItemNames.size();x++){
                JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(menuItemNames.get(x).toString());
                item.addActionListener(this);
                listItemSearchName.add(item);
            }
```

`listItemSearchName` is the menu the item is added to.

In my `actionPerformed` method I would like to be able to know when something from the `listItemSearchName` menu has been clicked on.

Comment: Well, if the actionPerformed() method of the listener is called, then something has been clicked. That's the whole point of the listener.

Comment: Also, check the `actionCommand` property of the `ActionListener`, which typically defaults to the text of the button.  You can also use `setActionCommand` on the `JMenuItem` to customise the value. Take a look at [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details